# which one is better practice to deliver email in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have following FakeMailer class for sending emails.

```
class FakeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def fake_method_1(recipient, subject)
    mail(to: email, subject: "#{Rails.env} - #{message}", body: body).deliver
  end

  def fake_method_2(recipient, subject)
    mail(to: email, subject: "#{Rails.env} - #{message}", body: body)
  end

end
```

Both of fake_method_1 and fake_method_2 send out the same email. I could do

```
FakeMailer.fake_method_1(recipient, subject)
FakeMailer.fake_method_2(recipient, subject).deliver
```

Which one is a better practice? In other words, should I return a mail instance then deliver, or deliver directly from FakeMailer class? What's the trade-off?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option.  What if someday you want to `deliver_later` instead?  I'm sure there are other reasons not to call `deliver` within the method as well.

Comment: Also it is about the single responsability principle, fake_method_1 has the responsability to create the email not to deliver it.

Answer (score 0):

The second one. I tried using the first method and it didn't work. I think it is because the mail falls out of scope.

Comment: Not sure what that means; you're calling `deliver` on the same object either way.